# replica aero form-shake / borderless form / panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What would be the simplest method of implementing 'windows aero form-shake' like functionality to a panel or borderless windows form?

For instance.  I have a borderless form which looks like this

[image]
I have some a class which contains some code that handles MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp.  I can include this in an edit if required (however this code also handles screen snapping and various other borderless required events and so it is quite long / complex).

The objective here is to make this static class I have so that it has 3 events MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp.  you would simply bind the MouseDown, MosueMove and MouseUp events of any Panel to these three methods stored in the class and this would enable dragging, snapping, and changing the window state (these three I  have already achieved) - but also to add a windows aero style method as well

here is a simplified version:

```
    public static void MouseDown(MouseEventArgs now) {
        if (!Dragging) {
            Dragging = true;
            Location = new Point(now.X, now.Y);
        }
    }
    public static void MouseMove(Form form, MouseEventArgs now) {
        TargetForm = form;
        if (Dragging) {
           ... <more code>
           IsDocked = false;
           TargetForm.Location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - (TargetForm.Width / 2), Cursor.Position.Y);
        }
        Point CurrentLocation = new Point();
        CurrentLocation = TargetForm.PointToScreen(now.Location);
        TargetForm.Location = new Point(CurrentLocation.X - Location.X, CurrentLocation.Y - Location.Y);
           ... <more code>
        }
    }
     public static void MouseUp(MouseEventArgs now) {
        if (Dragging) {
            Dragging = false;
            ... <more code>
       }
     }
```

I want to add in the ability to 'shake' the form.  I could do this by implementing another form type but this is not ideal.  I'm not sure how I would implement this into my existing code.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO; as it stands your question is a little too broad, and is likely to be closed. SO works best if you ask a question with a clear goal, as well as the research and attempts you've made so far to solve the problem. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information.

Comment: I have included some more detail which may help others to help me :)